# Need help for efficient groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df, which consists of information about clients, day of event and value spent:
[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX8TQ.png)

code to reproduce df:

```
d = {'CLIENT': ['John', 'Jonas', 'Mary', 'Anne', 'John', 'Jonas', 'Mary','John', 'Mary'],'SPENT': [30, 400, 800, 90, 180, 560, 50, 200, 100],'DAY_EVENT': ['WED', 'SAT', 'SUN', 'MON', 'FRI', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SUN']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I´ve first made an `df.groupby` with the following aggregation options:

```
df_cli = df.groupby('CLIENT').agg({'SPENT': [np.size, np.sum, np.mean]}).reset_index()
```

This leaves me with this:
[pandas groupby dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CaPT.png)

I want to determine the preferred and the least preferred days for my clients, but I don't know how to make this a variable to the `groupby` function, so I've tried with another `groupby` df:

```
df_cli_day = df.groupby(['CLIENT','DAY_EVENT']).agg({'SPENT':[np.size, np.sum, np.mean]}).reset_index(level=1)
```

and then I have this:
[another pandas groupby dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5NNE.png)

I've attempted doing this defining functions and then applying them to the dataframe, as following:

```
def preferred_day(row): 
   cli = df_cli['CLIENT'][row]
   clidays = df_cli_day.loc[cli]
   return clidays['DAY_EVENT'].max()

def least_preferred_day(row):
    cli = df_cli['CLIENT'][row]
    clidays = df_cli_day.loc[cli]
    return clidays['DAY_EVENT'].min()

df_cli['preferred_day'] = df_cli.apply(lambda row:  preferred_day(row), axis=1)
```

Which raises the following:

```
 ValueError: ('cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Since my functions works when called, I've worked around by looping and appending the results to a list, then transforming them into series, and finally assigning them to columns in the df, as in the code below:

```
preferred_list = []
least_preferred_list = []

for i in range(df_cli['CLIENT'].size): 
    preferred_list.append(preferred_day(i))
    least_preferred_list.append(least_preferred_day(i))

prefered_day_s = pd.Series(preferred_list)
least_preferred_day_s = pd.Series(least_preferred_list)
df_cli['preferred_day'] = preferred_day_s
df_cli['least_preferred_day'] = least_preferred_day_s
```

This yields me the result I want, but it's very slow.

I need a way to get rid of the ValueError when using `df.apply`, or another way to get the same results more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `ValueError` is occurring because `row` is a `Series` when passed to your function. This is the way `apply` works (see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)). You seem to expect `row` to be a numeric index, which is not correct. It should never be necessary to reference the original dataframe from within the function you passed to `apply`

You were on the right track with your second `groupby`, however the faster way to do this is to group in two stages, like so:

```
def most_frequent_day(group):
    ''' Return most frequent DAY_EVENT occurrence for group. '''
    return group['DAY_EVENT'].value_counts().apply(['max', 'idxmax'])

df.groupby('CLIENT').apply(most_frequent_day)
```

By using `apply` with `groupby`, the function `most_frequent_day` is called once for each client with the subset of entries in the original dataframe for that client. For each subset, you can then simply find the highest frequency of DAY_EVENT. This returns the result:

```
DAY_EVENT  max idxmax
CLIENT               
Anne         1    MON
John         2    FRI
Jonas        1    SAT
Mary         2    SUN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I didn't know these methods(?) 'max', 'idxmax' and I made another one with 'min', 'idxmin'.
  I'm still trying to figure how to use it to my end goal, where I want my first df_cli, with the agg functions [np.size, np.sum, np.mean] applied, and the most and leas frequent day as columns.
For example, the row for Jhon must be: 
size|sum|  mean   |most_freq_day|least_freq_day
 3   |410 | 136.66  |  FRI                | WED
I guess that to accomplish that I'm gonna need to change the return part of the function, but I still don't know how to apply

Comment: You should be able to use a simple `join` to merge the two grouped dataframes. Since they are both the result of grouping by CLIENT, they will have the same index (at least, before calling `reset_index`).

Comment: I got what I wanted, but used pd.merge:

df_cli1 = df.groupby('CLIENT').agg({'SPENT':[np.size, np.sum, p.mean]})

df_cli2 = df.groupby('CLIENT').apply(most_and_least_days*)
just included min and idxmin
df3 = df_cli1.merge(df_cli2, how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)
I guess that as you mentioned, the indexes are the same, both join and merge are safe and with same speed (but I can be wrong), and I still wonder if it's possible with one groupby call, but again, thank you, thank you **very much**